# After upgrading iPhone to iOS 17.1 Xcode does not show container content

Tags: ios, xcode

After Upgrading iPhone to iOS 17.1 Xcode stop showing container content.

Well, I tried many things like restarting everything, reseting Location & Privacy of iPhone etc.

Building and running application from Xcode works fine by the way.

I was doing something directory and file intensive  seeing directory structure would be helpful.

PS: Download container works.

Comment: But 'Download container' does not contain cache folder.